# How to give border styles to Material UI TableRow Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI [Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) component in my project. I want to give border styles for the TableRow Component. I am using scss classNames to give styling to the component. Usually the border styling is handled in the TableCell, but it doesn't suite my requirement. Is there any way I can give border styling to TableRow ?

TableRow API - https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/#css

I have made a Codesandbox Implementation [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-smoke-1wofe?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to remove bottom border of `TableCell`s

Add this CSS rule to `demo.scss`

```
.MuiTableCell-root {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```